# how to configure service for prometheus instead of executing port-forward command everytime

Tags: prometheus-operator

Every time I execute this command to bring up the prometheus dashboard.

```
kubectl port-forward -n monitoring prometheus-prometheus-operator-prometheus-0 9090
```

Is there any workaround to have the service running all the time without executing the command?

Note: Prometheus operator is deployed in Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your service of **Prometheus** as **LoadBalancer** which will give you IP to access the service directly without running a y command.

You can expose your service as **NodePort** also as per need.

you can read more about the **service type** and **changing type** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

if you are using the Nginx ingress inside the Kubernetes you can also expose your service as the ingress and use that domain to access the Prometheus.